# Detecting velocity in a specific threshold

Tags: measurement, velocity

I have three velocity sensors that are axis in 3D. 
I would like to know the best method to do basic ON/OFF trigger..
I'm thinking of a hystersis control, is there a method that can detect if the velocity from all the three sensors exceed a specific range like 10 m/s?

Comment: 2 sensors or 3? "Exceed a specific range" can mean outside of a range - what do you mean?

Comment: sorry three sensors, yes if its outside a range. sorry for miss-clarification

Comment: It's called the greater than symbol, it looks like this: > . Compare two values (probably the total velocity would be best) against a  threshold to detect the velocity you desire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> yes if its outside a range

If you need to detect whether a signal is outside a range you need a window comparator like this: -

[image]

It uses (or can use) two op-amps where one op-amp detects a high threshold and the other op-amp detects a low threshold. If the signal is between the two thresholds you get a logic 1 output and if it's outside the range then you get a logic zero.

This would need to be triplicated for three sensors and you could use a three input OR gate (for example) to detect the situation where all three signals are outside their specific range.

Comment: I mean in software not in hardware, sorry about not saying so..

Comment: You can implement a window comparator in software; if A > UPPER_LIMIT then blah blah blah.

Comment: Can you calify the situation with the three OR gates ? couldn't understand it, I mean you can explain the block diagram. What I understand is after the three OP-AMPs I need to and the three sensor results.. ?\

Comment: also how would I determine Uref top, according to the velocity, it will be the max speed ?

Comment: A window comparator uses (for example) 2 op-amps and an AND gate. The AND gate is shown inside the blue box marked "&". That is for 1 channel. To combine three channels like the one I have shown, you would need an OR gate with three inputs and, a zero on the OR gate's output indicates that all three channels are detecting an "out of range" situation.

Comment: Uref top is a voltage equivalent to the voltage produced by the sensor when it is borderline above the range. Uref bot is the same but for under range. If using software then U ref's are whatever the digital equivalent numbers are for your upper and lower limits.

Comment: @AhmedSaleh  why don't you edit your question to include everything you'd like to know?